# c++ function like printf

Tags: c++, c

i have this function

```
char* copy(char* pString,...){
    char *vToate;
    int vLen;
    va_list vAp;
    va_start(vAp,pString);
    vLen+=strlen(pString);
    va_end(vAp);

    vToate=new char[vLen+1];

    va_list vAp1;
    va_start(vAp1,pString);
    strncpy(vToate,pString,strlen(pString));
    va_end(vAp1);
    return vToate;
}
```

if i try this

```
char *vTest="test";
char *vTmp=copy(vTest," ",vTest);
cout<<vTmp;
```

the result are "test" not "test test"
what are wrong ?

Comment: What does this have in common with `printf`?

Comment: And where's the initialization of `vLen`? You use `operator +=` on uninitialized value or this is not the whole code?

Comment: You're never calling `va_arg()` to iterate over the argument lists. You also don't initialize `vLen`, so you end up allocating an undefined amount of memory with `new char[]`. I'm surprised this program doesn't crash right away most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks you're unclear about how to use variadic macros. You forgot to call va_arg to get each next element. You also need a length or sentinel value, so you can know when there aren't any more arguments. It seems like you want this:

```
char *copy(char *str, ...)
{
    va_arg ap;
    va_start(str, ap);
    int len = 0;
    char *sp;
    for(sp=str; sp; sp=va_arg(ap, char*))
        len+=strlen(sp);
    va_end(ap);
    va_start(ap);
    char *dst = new char[len+1];
    int pos = 0;        
    for(sp=str; sp; sp=va_arg(ap, char*)){
        memcpy(dst+pos, sp, strlen(sp));
        pos+=strlen(sp);
    }
    va_end(ap);
    dst[pos] = '\0';
    return dst;
}
```

Which you would then call:

```
char *str = copy("foo", " ", "bar", NULL);
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you expect `va_start`/`va_end` to do a sort of loop over the parameters. That's not the case at all, you need to do the iteration yourself.

But variadic functions don't provide a way of getting the number of arguments passed, so you can't loop safely the way you are doing it either. You'll need to:

- Change the first parameter so that it indicates the number of arguments you're passing.
- Change the calling convention so you allways pass a `NULL` as the last argument.

Both of there are error-prone and require careful coding at the call sites, which is not great.

Look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_start/) for an example of how to iterate over the parameters.

You should really consider using `std::string`s. They have a handy `operator+`, so you don't have to do any of that trickery.

If you really do want to do it the hard way, make sure that:

- You initialize your local `vLen` parameter
- Use `strcat` to concatenate C-style strings (safe as long as you really did allocate enough memory, but not the most efficient here)

Answer (score 0):

The critical line is this one:

```
strncpy(vToate,pString,strlen(pString));
```

You're copying the contents of the argument string to the beginning of your output string. You need to given *strncpy()* a pointer past the point of your last copy so that you're appending data rather than overwriting.

```
char* vCpy = vToate;
int len = 0;
va_list vAp1;
    va_start(vAp1,pString);
        len = strlen( pString );
        strncpy( vCpy, pString, len );
        vCpy += len;
va_end(vAp1);
```

The above comments also apply.

Answer (score 0):

What you miss is some loop, extracting `va_arg`. Also, you give no hints as to how many arguments you're passing, you should either terminate the list with `NULL` or pass the number.

Answer (score 0):

What you have produced isn't really C++, but in terms of the output you are seeing I believe:

```
strncpy(vToate,pString,strlen(pString));
```

Is merely taking pString (which contains the string "test") and copying it directly to vToate. So what you return is the string "test".

There are numerous ways to concatenate various data types to a single string in C++, but the one I find the most simple is using std:stringstream:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << vTest << " " << vTest;
char* vTmp = ss.str();
cout << vTmp;
```